# iphone socket disconnecting after 1 min

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, ios4, network-programming

We have following code for connecting to our server. This is part of iPhone App.

Problem is that  recv(CFSocketGetNative(inSocketRef), &length, sizeof(length), 0);
call returns 0 after exactly 60 sec. We are not sending anything from server. I want it to wait for data or disconnection (either server or client initiated). However, it always returns after 60 sec.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

```
 void CallbackHandlerConnectionHandler(CFSocketRef inSocketRef, CFSocketCallBackType inType,
                 CFDataRef inAddress, const void *inData, void *inInfo)
{

ChatServerConnectionHandler *conHandler = (ChatServerConnectionHandler *)inInfo;

if([conHandler respondsToSelector:@selector(dataRecievedFromServer:)])
{
    int res = 0;
    SInt32 length;
    res = recv(CFSocketGetNative(inSocketRef), &length, sizeof(length), MSG_PEEK);


    if(0 >= res || (length < 0))
    {
        //Disconnect the connection, as some has occcured in the sockets..
        [conHandler performSelector:@selector(errorEncountered)];

        NSLog(@"Error occured in server!!");
        return;
    }


    printf ("good data")
}
}

-(BOOL) connectToServer:(NSString *)ipAddress Port:(int)portNumber
{       
connectionState = eConnectionEstablishInProgress;
self.threadStopped = NO;
CFRunLoopSourceRef source;

int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

struct hostent *host;
host = gethostbyname([ipAddress cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct timeval timeout;

if (sockfd < 0)
{  
    error("ERROR opening socket");
    connectionState = eNoConnection;
    return NO;
}


bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
bzero(&(serv_addr.sin_zero),8); 


/* Creates a CFSocket object for a pre-existing native socket */
CFSocketContext socketContext={0,self,NULL,NULL,NULL};
socketRef   = CFSocketCreateWithNative(kCFAllocatorDefault,  
                                       sockfd, 
                                       kCFSocketReadCallBack, 
                                       CallbackHandlerConnectionHandler, 
                                       &socketContext);

source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, socketRef, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), source, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
CFRelease(source);
source = nil;

InstallSignalHandlers();

CFDataRef socketAddress;
socketAddress = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (UInt8 *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr), kCFAllocatorNull);
CFSocketError result=CFSocketConnectToAddress(socketRef, socketAddress, 0);
CFRelease(socketAddress);

if(kCFSocketSuccess == result)
{
    //printf("Socket connection established");
    self.serverRunning = YES;
    connectionState = eConnectionEstablised;
    NSLog(@"\nCall Connection accepted callback.");
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(conectionEstablishedWithTheServer)])
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(conectionEstablishedWithTheServer)];
    }

}
else
{
    //printf("Unable to create socket why???***");
    connectionState = eNoConnection;
    if(socketRef)
        CFRelease(socketRef);
    socketRef = nil;
    return NO;
}

while(FALSE == self.threadStopped)
{
    CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1, FALSE);
}
NSLog(@"\nOut of Server socket connection thread.");

self.serverRunning = NO;


if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(conectionFinishedWithServer)])
{
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(conectionFinishedWithServer)];
}

if(socketRef)
{
    if(CFSocketIsValid(socketRef))
        CFSocketInvalidate(socketRef);
}


return YES;
}
```

Comment: After 60 sec, I get following packet (captured through wireshark) <br>      966 68.092091000 122.248.244.87 192.168.1.115 TCP 66 8475 > 51930 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=5888 Len=0 TSval=261523689 TSecr=764650529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a server problem - or rather functionality: closing inactive connections to keep enough free resources.

If you didn't write the server code try to contact the author.

The packet you mention [FIN, ACK] is a packet that closes your socket: you should check the IP adresses but the server is most probably the initiator of this packet.

Comment: We found the problem. The server runs behind AWS load balancer. after every 60 sec, if the connection is idle, load balancer sends a FIN. For the time being, we have stopped using load balancer. We would probably build a periodic heartbeat solution to make sure that socket is not in idle state.

Comment: Good to hear that. And 'heartbeat solution' is also a good idea when you're planning to keep a connection open for a longer time.